# Permission denied error trying to commit to Subversion

Tags: svn

I can checkout but I can't checkin

The error is  svn: Can't open file '/Users/Shared/svn/test/db/txn-current-lock': Permission denied

What can I do to fix this

Comment: Could you return the output of `ls -l /Users/Shared/svn/test/db/txn-current-lock`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you in the same group as the owner of the files in the svn repository directories ?
Are the files group writable ?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried doing the command "svn cleanup" sometimes it helps with random svn problems

Comment: Helped some. But didn't fully fix the issue.